# Facing problem generating subgraph from original graph in neo4j and networkX

Tags: python, neo4j, networkx

I am trying to build up a  subgraph from  original graph , the scenario is given below

[image]

Here nodes b and C are connected with node A. My desired output is if two nodes are connected with a common node then they are connected. How can I solve this with neo4j or networkX? My focus is on neo4j for cypher query but they have networkX binding as well. I am using python for developing this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like this in mind?

## 1. Creating your model

For the ease of possible further answers and solutions I note my graph creating statement:

```
CREATE
    (nodeA:Node {name:'Node A'}),
    (nodeB:Node {name:'Node B'}),
    (nodeC:Node {name:'Node C'}),
    (nodeD:Node {name:'Node D'}),
    (nodeE:Node {name:'Node E'}),
    (nodeF:Node {name:'Node F'}),
    (nodeA)-[:CONNECTED]->(nodeB),
    (nodeA)-[:CONNECTED]->(nodeC),
    (nodeC)-[:CONNECTED]->(nodeD),
    (nodeD)-[:CONNECTED]->(nodeE),
    (nodeD)-[:CONNECTED]->(nodeF);
```

[image: initial situation graph]

## 2. Variant I (not graph changing)

### 2.1 Solution

```
MATCH
    path = (sourceNode:Node)<-[:CONNECTED]-(:Node)-[:CONNECTED]->(targetNode:Node)
WHERE
    id(sourceNode)<id(targetNode)
RETURN
    sourceNode, targetNode;
```

The second line describes your two-nodes-with-a-common-node-between pattern, while line four filters the resulting pairs for one direction only.

### 2.2 Result

```
╒═════════════════╤═════════════════╕
│"sourceNode"     │"targetNode"     │
╞═════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│{"name":"Node B"}│{"name":"Node C"}│
├─────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│{"name":"Node E"}│{"name":"Node F"}│
└─────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

## 3. Variant II (graph extending)

### 3.1 Solution

The following Cypher query enrich your existing graph by direct relationships (`NEW_CONNECTED`) between depended nodes.

```
MATCH
    path = (sourceNode:Node)<-[:CONNECTED]-(:Node)-[:CONNECTED]->(targetNode:Node)
WHERE
    id(sourceNode)<id(targetNode)
MERGE 
    (sourceNode)<-[:NEW_CONNECTED]-(targetNode);
```

### 3.2 Result

[image: resulting graph]

Comment: thanks for your answer @ThirstForKnowledgwe.  I need the variation like  assume There are many records in node C  like c1 c2 ... Cn. if  c1 and c2  is connected with common node A then I will create a separate relation  c1 ---connected -- c2 . I don't want to show Node A here.  my desire output will be c1---connected--c2 if  and only if c1 and c2  has common relation with node A. and for your information my node size is 8 million and relation ship size 789000457. I have 240G ram and 16 core cpu in my cloud